# How to add a custom tag in contact form 7 and change the output in email?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-contact-form-7

I need dynamic number of input fields i.e. Question and answers in Contact form 7 with my custom form Field it's been generated based on the question set suits a candidate it can 1 or it can 10 also here is what i have added just to make it short i have hardcoded everything instead of showing you database queries and loops

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'my_questions_field' );

function my_questions_field() {
   wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'my_questions', 'my_custom_question_form_tag_handler' , array( 'name-attr' => true ) );
}

function my_custom_question_form_tag_handler( $tag ) { 
    $input ='<label>Ques1?</label><input value="Ques1?" name="tag[]" type="hidden">';
    $input .= '<input name="ans[]"  type="text" value="ans1">';
    $input .= '<label>Ques2?</label><input name="tag[]"  value="Ques2?" type="hidden">';
    $input .= '<input name="ans[]"  type="text" value="ans2">';
    return $input;
}
```

added :

```
[tag]
[ans]
```

in contact form 7 emails from the backend

The caveat here is  i don't know the number of question it will going to render it is base on some of my custom queries
the number of question may vary from 1-10 or maybe even more that's why i have used this syntax.

the output in email i am getting is

```
Ques1?,Ques2? 
ans1,ans2
```

What i need in email is

```
Ques1: Ans1
Ques2: Ans2
```

I have found the function in  contact-form-7/includes/functions.php

```
function wpcf7_flat_join( $input ) {
 $input = wpcf7_array_flatten( $input );
 $output = array();

 foreach ( (array) $input as $value ) {
  $output[] = trim( (string) $value );
 }

 return implode( ',', $output );
}
```

and of email function contact-form-7/includes/mail.php

```
private function replace_tags_callback( $matches, $html = false ) {
  // allow [[foo]] syntax for escaping a tag
  if ( $matches[1] == '[' && $matches[4] == ']' ) {
   return substr( $matches[0], 1, -1 );
  }

  $tag = $matches[0];
  $tagname = $matches[2];
  $values = $matches[3];

  if ( ! empty( $values ) ) {
   preg_match_all( '/"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'/', $values, $matches );
   $values = wpcf7_strip_quote_deep( $matches[0] );
  }

  $do_not_heat = false;

  if ( preg_match( '/^_raw_(.+)$/', $tagname, $matches ) ) {
   $tagname = trim( $matches[1] );
   $do_not_heat = true;
  }

  $format = '';

  if ( preg_match( '/^_format_(.+)$/', $tagname, $matches ) ) {
   $tagname = trim( $matches[1] );
   $format = $values[0];
  }
```

in Class `WPCF7_MailTaggedText`

but not able to find the proper solution

just want contact form 7 to treat inputs from que and ans tag differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first step, the form to display, you can keep what you have coded.

Then you can do that to generate the result in the e-mail :

```
add_filter("wpcf7_posted_data", function ($posted_data) {

    $result = "";


    foreach ($posted_data["tag"] as $index => $question) {

        $answer = $posted_data["ans"][$index];

        $result .= "$question : $answer\n";

    }


    $posted_data["my_questions"] = $result;

    return $posted_data;

});
```

And in the configuration of the e-mail, just put the tag `[my_questions]`

Comment: Thank you.. it works like a charm.. but it would be much better if you can tell me the answer of additional part of the question.

Comment: which additional part ? my code output in the e-mail the informations that you ask.

Comment: sorry.. but the edit of my question is till pending for review.. so thank you.. actually i wanted the same thing to show on the flamingo database.. now there are 3 fields myquestion, tag and ans.. i only need my questions as other two are repeating.

Comment: I don't see pending edit in your question. it may be better to create a new question.

Comment: here is my new question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290895/how-to-hide-some-of-the-data-of-contact-form-7-in-flamingo-plugin